# how to use strings as associative array keys?

Tags: associative-array, autohotkey

I am writing a simple GUI in AutoHotkey, one of the elements is the ability to associate a number with a button label:

```
Call:
{
book := {"Tel Maison": 8912, "Tel Mobile": 000000}
nr := book[%A_GuiControl%]
MsgBox %A_GuiControl% - number: %nr%
}

CapsLock::
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, Tel Maison
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, Tel Mobile
Gui, Show
```

When running this script I get, upon pressing a button, an error message (*The following variable name contains an illegal caracter: "Tel Maison"*) pointing to

```
nr := book[%A_GuiControl%]
```

I believe that this is due to the space character in the label name.

**Q1: isn't it possible to use hash keys with a space?**

I modified the script to

```
Call:
{
book := {"TelMaison": 8912, "TelMobile": 000000}
nr := book[%A_GuiControl%]
MsgBox %A_GuiControl% - number: %nr%
}

CapsLock::
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, TelMaison
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, TelMobile
Gui, Show
```

It now runs but the variable `nr` is empty.

**Q2: The label is passed via `A_GuiControl` as a string, right? If so why isn't there a match for the key in the example above?**

I also tried to use `book := {TelMaison: 8912, TelMobile: 000000}` but the result is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical example of expressions vs. string literals in AHK, which can be troublesome in some cases. In order to use variable contents as a key for an object, simply put the variable in the brackets and **don't enclose them in percentage signs (`%`)**:

```
nr := book[A_GuiControl]
```

This way, you can very well use spaces for the button names.

**What's the problem with** `book[%A_GuiControl%]`**?**
AHK expects either a hard-coded string (e.g. `book["Tel Maison"]`) or a variable when you access an object property by key. Since we don't pass it a hard string, it's assuming that `TelMaison` or `Tel Maison` is the variable name. Accessing `Tel Maison` will directly lead to a runtime error, since variable names can't have spaces. `TelMaison` is legal, but contains nothing. So basically, we access the object with an empty string as the key (like `book[""]`). This, by the way, isn't illegal and you could in fact use the empty string as a key, although I think that's not reasonable in most cases.

**Why does AHK offer this weird syntax then?**
There are scenarios in which you might want to use the contents of a variable in turn as a variable name. Look at this example for instance:

```
TelMaison := 8912
TelMobile := 0
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, TelMaison
Gui, Add, Button, gCall, TelMobile
Gui, Show

Exit

Call:
    nr := %A_GuiControl%
    msgbox % nr
return
```

With `nr := %A_GuiControl%`, `nr` is assigned the value of the variable, whose name is equal to the contents of `A_GuiControl`. I wouldn't recommend this pattern though, since it's very error-prone and simply bad design.